# Area of click-selected features PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgsvectorlayer

I'm trying to get the total area for a reprojected layer made by number of features selected by clicking on a layer with PyQGIS, but when I use `iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()` a list of QgsFeatures is returned, not a QgsVectorLayer, so I have to convert back again to QgsVectorLayer or add these features to a layer, but so far I haven't been able to find how to do this.

The code I've been using:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()
parameter = {'INPUT': layer, 'TARGET_CRS': 'EPSG:32615','OUTPUT': 'memory:Reprojected'}
result = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', parameter)
areatot = 0
for elem in result['OUTPUT'].getFeatures():
     geom = elem.geometry()
     areatot += geom.area()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach to what I was trying to achieve was to use the `QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), True)`, this I found by reprojecting a layer using clicking menu, and checking the log, then I added this to the code I had to end up with this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
parameter = { 'INPUT' : QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer.id(), True), 'OUTPUT' : 'memory:', 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32615') }
result = processing.run('native:reprojectlayer', parameter)
areatot = 0
for elem in result['OUTPUT'].getFeatures():
     geom = elem.geometry()
     areatot += geom.area()
```